# javascript filter and include method usage in nested array object

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
      const post =  {
      title: 'New Title',
      _id: '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7b',
      content: '',
      data: [],
      images: [
        {
          data: [],
          _id: '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c',
          width: 473,
          height: 1000
        },
        {
          data: [],
          _id: '5e5782e7f695d70b6e376c82',
          width: 601,
          height: 1000
        }
      ],
      timestamp: 1582793412754
    }
    const rec_id = '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c';

 const myId = '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376d4d';

   if(post.images.some(img => img._id === rec_id)) {

    const data = post.images.data.filter(id => id.toString() !== myId.toString());

        let isData = false;
        if (data.length === post.data.length) {
          data.push(myId);
          isData = true;
        }
        post.image.data = data;
     } 
    console.log(post)
```

Here, rec_id is match by post.images._id, I want to add myId inside post.images.data array if myId is found same inside post.images.data array then toggle the value add and remove base on rec_id if other myId found it should push value. Tried this way doesn't get success can you please guide how to make this.

Thanks

Output should be

```
const post =  {
  title: 'New Title',
  _id: '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7b',
  content: '',
  data: [],
  images: [
    {
      data: ['5e5782c4f695d70b6e376d4d'],
      _id: '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c',
      width: 473,
      height: 1000
    },
    {
      data: [],
      _id: '5e5782e7f695d70b6e376c82',
      width: 601,
      height: 1000
    }
  ],
  timestamp: 1582793412754
}
```

Comment: what is myId? a property or an object ?

Comment: Its just a string const myId = '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376d4d';

Comment: const myRec = post.myRec.filter(id => id.toString() !== myId.toString());

    let isData = false;
    if (myRec.length === post.myRec.length) {
      myRec.push(myId);
      isData = true;
    }
    post.myRec = myRec;

 console.log(post);

This works fine if I do put this myRec = [ ]; under content object but no idea how to do same things inside images.data array

Comment: Here is what I have understood. If myId is not found under post.image.data array, then we need to push myId in the array. If myId is found there, then we need to remove that object from image array?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking

Comment: ok, I am halfway there.

Comment: But myId should be unique if difference ID found can be store into this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this way also

```
const post = {
    title: 'New Title',
    _id: '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7b',
    content: '',
    data: [],
    images: [{
            data: [],
            _id: '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c',
            width: 473,
            height: 1000
        },
        {
            data: [],
            _id: '5e5782e7f695d70b6e376c82',
            width: 601,
            height: 1000
        }
    ],
    timestamp: 1582793412754
}

const doc_id = '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c';

const myId = '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376d4d';

if (post.images.some(img => img._id == doc_id)) {
    post.images.forEach(function (e, i) {
        if (post.images[i]._id == doc_id) {
            data = post.images[i].data.filter(userId => userId.toString() !== myId.toString());
            let isData = false;
            if (data.length === post.images[i].data.length) {
                data.push(myId);
                isData = true;
            }
            post.images[i].data = data;
            return data;
        }
    })
}
console.log(post);
```

Answer (score 0):

If myId is not found under post.image.data array, then we need to push myId in the array.

Below is the working snippet with above logic:

```
 const post =  {
  title: 'New Title',
  _id: '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7b',
  content: '',
  data: [],
  images: [
    {
      data: [],
      _id: '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c',
      width: 473,
      height: 1000
    },
    {
      data: [],
      _id: '5e5782e7f695d70b6e376c82',
      width: 601,
      height: 1000
    }
  ],
  timestamp: 1582793412754
}
  const rec_id = '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c';
  const myId = '5e5782c4f695d70b6e376d4d';

 if(post.images.some(img => img._id === rec_id)) {
   post.images.forEach(function(e,i){
   if (post.images[i]._id == rec_id) { //myid is added only if rec_id matches
     if (post.images[i].data.length==0){
            post.images[i].data.push(myId);
      }
     else{
             const data = post.images[i].data.filter(id => id.toString() !== myId.toString());
              if (data.length>0)  post.images[i].data.push(myId);
      }
     }
    });
  } 
 console.log(post)
```

Comment: Why both images.data added same id it should be added to first one whose id is 5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c because rec_id match with only with first index of post.image._id;

Comment: data: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
images: Array(2)
0:
data: ["5e5782c4f695d70b6e376d4d"]
height: 1000
width: 473
_id: "5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7c"
__proto__: Object
1:
data: [" "]
height: 1000
width: 601
_id: "5e5782e7f695d70b6e376c82"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
timestamp: 1582793412754
title: "New Title"
_id: "5e5782c4f695d70b6e376c7b"

Should be like tis